# Why can I not convert a Foo<Bar> to IFoo<IBar>

Tags: c#, .net

Why can I not convert a `Foo<Bar>` to `IFoo<IBar>`.

If I try I get:

> There is no implicit reference conversion from `Foo<Bar>` to `IFoo<IBar>`

Comment: Does Foo implement IFoo?

Comment: Does `Foo` implement `IFoo` and `Bar` implement `IBar`?

Comment: Show: (1) your definition of Foo, in particular what interfaces it implements. (2) the code you use in the attempt to "convert."

Comment: Of course does Foo implement IFoo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would work if you were using C# 4 and `IFoo` were declared as:

```
public interface IFoo<out T>
```

assuming that `Bar` implements `IBar` and `Foo<T>` implements `IFoo<T>`.

However, it could only be declared that way if it were safe. It's *not* safe if `T` values "go into" the API as well as coming out. For example:

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This *can't* be covariant in T, as otherwise you could write:

```
public class StringFoo : IFoo<string>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

IFoo<string> fooString = new StringFoo(); // That's fine
IFoo<object> fooObject = fooString;       // This isn't, because...
fooObject.Value = new Object();           // ... this would violate type safety
```

Read Eric Lippert's [long blog series on generic variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) for much more information.

Comment: The problem was solved by adding out to the declaration of the interface. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work, three things need to be true:

1. `Bar` must implement `IBar`
2. `Foo` must implement `IFoo`
3. `IFoo<T>` must be covariant in `T` (like this: `IFoo<out T>`)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of C# you are compiling with.

Generic covariance and contravariance was introduced with C# and .NET 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx